# Email Verification for Paid Subscription-based App

Tags: registration, email, payment

We're developing a paid, subscription-based application and are currently contemplating different sign up flows. How does one go about verifying the users email address elegantly?

Email addresses are needed for:

- Payment reminders, receipts
- Password resets
- User ids
- Other forms of communication

Current ideas:

- Verification before sign up
  User enters an email address and receives an email with a link to the actual sign up and payment page (somewhat like an invitation)
- Standard sign up with verification before payment screen
  Seems disruptive to the sign up flow
- Standard sign up with verification after payment
  Dangerous if the user enters an incorrect email

Disclosure: Also posted on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/User-Experience/How-does-one-elegantly-handle-email-verification-for-a-subscription-based-app)

Comment: First, you should perhaps define your reasons for verifying email addresses. Is it for legal/regulatory compliance? Is it an essential (only) form of contact? Is it for security? Is it for marketing?

Comment: Some essentials include payment receipts, payment reminders, password resets.

Comment: I would definitely refrain from your third option of a standard sign up with verification after payment. It would be a major security issue if people entered the wrong email address.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR;**

Verification before sign up: No!
Verification as an integrated part of the sign up flow: Yes.

Assuming it's **1st priority is to get users to sign up to grow the user base** and being able to approach them. If yes, then I could think of the following flow:

- have them **sign up with the minimum amount of information necessary** to sign them up, incl. email and password, but no payment information yet
- show a **confirmation message** that they're **almost there but need to click the link in the email** you just sent to their email address
- (make sure you repeat the email address in the confirmation message so that they can double check if they entered the correct one)
- **send them an email and ask them to click the link** to verify their email address
- the **link should send them to the page being logged in** and show a confirmation message that says that they successfully signed up
- if you want, you could build the app in a way that they can't do anything without entering payment information to use the app (but you could also make a part of the content available for free, as a teaser)
- **make it crystal clear for users *before the sign* up that it's a paid service** because otherwise they're potentially annoyed and hate the app as they signed up without actually being prepared to pay